# site url change by htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

this is my project site **http://readysolution.info/usjobs/test-category/?cpid=2&c_id=acc/**

i just needed show url by  **http://readysolution.info/usjobs/XXXX/YYYY/VVVVV**   instead of this

**test-category/?cpid=2&c_id=acc/**

this is possible by .htaccess that my site url will be show by this new format . whetver will be display after /usjobs , it will be replace another word

example : 1) if it have  **/usjobs/test-category/?cpid=2&c_id=acc/** , then it will be **usjobs/XXXX/YYYY/VVVVV**

2) 1) if it have  **/usjobs/test-category/?cpid=2** , then it will be **usjobs/DDDD/KKKKK**

please helpl me !!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an htaccess Rewrite to "translate" a requesting URI into a WP URI. For example:

Request in the browser:  mysite.com/seg_1/wp_post_slug/seg_2

With a Rewrite you can ask for mysite/com/wp_post_slug and you'll be fine.

Please note:

1) The above is pseudo code for reference purposes and might not be accurate.

2) Somewhere in the requesting RI you're going to have to have something that can be used to identify the page / post you actually want requested. For example you can't have a request of mysite.com/xxx/yyy/zzz and then somehow have a rewrite serve you mysite.com/bbb. The bbb has to be in the request so you can use the rewrite to parse it out. (Note: Actually, tere probably is a work around for this but then you're going to have to maintain some sort of reference / conversion table.)